# How can I reduce the access time on large Excel files?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlrd

I would like to process a large data set of a mechanical testing device with Python. The  software of this device only allows to export the data as an Excel file. Therefore, I use the `xlrd` package which works fine for small `*.xlsx` files.

The problem I have is, that when I want to open a common data set (3-5 MB) by

```
  xlrd.open_workbook(path_wb)
```

the access time is about 30s to 60s. Is there any more effecitve and faster way to access Excel files?

Comment: Have you tried using the keyword argument `on_demand=False`, to avoid loading the whole workbook at once? See [the documentation](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966).

Comment: Hi! on_demand=False is the default value, when I change that to 'True' it seems to be faster but the application is not really stable anymore. Thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant setting it to `True`!

Answer (score 0):

You could access the file as a database via [PyPyODBC](https://github.com/jiangwen365/pypyodbc) instead, which may (or may not) be faster - you'd have to try it out and compare the results.

This method should work for both `.xls` and `.xlsx` files. Unfortunately, it comes with a couple of caveats:

1. As far as I am aware, this will **only work on Windows** machines, since you're relying on the Microsoft Jet database driver.
2. The Microsoft Jet database driver **can be rather buggy**, especially with dates.
3. It's **not possible to create or modify** Excel files (a note in the PyPyODBC [`exceltests.py`](https://github.com/jiangwen365/pypyodbc/blob/master/exceltests.py) file says: `I have not been able to successfully create or modify Excel files.`). Your question seems to indicate that you're only interested in *reading* files, though, so hopefully this will not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think thats worth a try. As you said, I just want to read and process the data. Do you have an idea if any other file format would help to access the data faster? Like .xlsb, CSV or whatever

Comment: Perhaps, but the time taken to convert the Excel file into a different format might cancel out any potential speed-of-access gains.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that it wasn't actually the problem with the access time but I created an object in the same step. Now, by creating the object separately everything works fast and nice.